# Android RadioButton select drawable

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

Setting page with `RadioButton`. The `RadioButton` extends the entire width of the screen. But it shows extremely awkward animation when i click it.

[image: example]

And here is my `xml` below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/xxx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        style="@style/Settings_group.Item"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:text="xxx" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_setting_item_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        style="@style/Settings_group.Item"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
        android:text="xxx" />

</RadioGroup>
```

**EDIT-1**
I hope the ripple effect should shows at single line of `RadioButton`, but not at center of screen. Just like this

[image: correct]

Comment: Please be More Specific by explaining ,What you want to achieve ?

Comment: @AdarshGumashta Sry, see my edit-1 please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the radioButton background to `android:background="?selectableItemBackground"` don't use `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: @L.Meng awesome